# Minimal build.gradle for Android library modules

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

At the moment (Android Studio 0.8.6 with Android SDK tools 23.0.2), this is the build.gradle of a new Android Library, as generated by the wizard:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.mylibrary"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project (':model')
}
```

What can we safely remove from there? That is, what is the absolute minimum we should have in a Gradle file for an Android library?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why are you trying to remove things from the build file? With more details you can get a better answer.

Comment: Just because I don't like having information that is not useful, and that may end up obsolete. Is this applicationId useful at all, what if I upgrde the targetSdkVersion of the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Required. This tells the Gradle build system what plugins to load in order to do the build. Without this it has no idea how to build your project.

---

```
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
```

Both of these are required by the Android-Gradle plugin, and you'll get an error without them.

---

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mycompany.mylibrary"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

This isn't strictly required, and your build will succeed without it (provided you supply the values *somewhere*; you can't merely delete this from your build file without doing anything else and not break your project), but it's considered idiomatic in Android-Gradle projects. These values are plugged into the AndroidManifest.xml that's generated as part of the manifest merge and which gets built into your project; the values you specify here replace any values that you actually put in the AndroidManifest.xml file yourself. `applicationId` corresponds to the `package` attribute of the `manifest` tag and is critical.

Unfortunately, this is the cause of some confusion for Android developers used to Eclipse, who tend to modify the manifest because that's how things used to be done, and are confused when those changes get overridden by the build file.

Why have these things moved from the manifest to the build file? Because in Gradle you can have the notion of build types and flavors, and these values can vary depending on which flavor + type combination is being built. Expressing these values in the build script instead of through a multitude of partial AndroidManifest.xml files is likely to be far more convenient.

---

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

This section (at least the stub `release` build type) may not be strictly necessary. The build system creates debug and release build types automatically so you don't need to tell it to create the release build. According to the docs (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide), `runProguard` is already false for release builds, and if you're not running Proguard, there's not a lot of need to specify its config files. As much as anything this is here as a reminder of how to set this up if you need Proguard, which is a pretty common thing for release builds and something all developers should consider when getting their apps ready for public release.

Comment: I get an error "library projects cannot set applicationId" when I try to set an application id in the defaultConfig... Looks like for libraries the package name is the only thing required in the AndroidManifest.xml...

Comment: Since '2018, `buildToolsVersion` is not required anymore.